# How to create list with multi columns in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create table with multi columns using SwiftUI. Is there any better way for same?

In list first columns has text which can be multiline.

Thank You for help

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code implemented to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `List` with an `HStack` containing your images.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 50) { index in
                HStack {
                    Text("some text")

                    Spacer()

                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .frame(width: 50)

                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .frame(width: 50)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]